# Get indexPath for mapView Annotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am loading a bunch of pins on a map using data from a plist. Here is how I get the data:

```
for (int i=0; i<self.dataArray.count; i++){

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *array = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Locations"];

    for (int i=0; i<array.count; i++){

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        double latitude = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =
            latitude, .longitude =  longitude};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord};

        MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];

        NSString *cityState = [dictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
        cityState = [cityState stringByAppendingString:@", "];
        NSString *state = [dictionary objectForKey:@"State"];
        cityState = [cityState stringByAppendingString:state];
        annotation.subtitle = cityState;
        annotation.coordinate = region.center;
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

Now for every annotation, I have added a detailDisclosureButton. I want to show details for that particular location from the plist. The problem is I need the indexPath.section and indexPath.row.

How can I get the indexPath of the pin? Is there a way to find the indexPath of the dictionary the annotation title is populated from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tracking the "section" and "row", I suggest storing a reference to the `dictionary` itself in the annotation object.

In the `MapAnnotation` class, add a property to hold a reference to the source dictionary:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *sourceDictionary;
```

When creating the annotation (in your existing loop), set this property along with the `title`, etc:

```
annotation.sourceDictionary = dictionary;
annotation.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Then in the detail button handler method (assuming you are using the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method), you cast the annotation object to your class and you'll be able to access the original dictionary the annotation came from:

```
MapAnnotation *mapAnn = (MapAnnotation *)view.annotation;
NSLog(@"mapAnn.sourceDictionary = %@", mapAnn.sourceDictionary);
```

Comment: Your a genius! Worked exactly like you explained. Thanks!